# iOS7 iPad Landscape only app, using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I believe this is a common issue and many answers don't work anymore, many just partial, if you are under iOS7 and your iPad app is Landscape only, but you want to use the `UIImagePickerController` with source `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` or `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`.

How to set it right, so it's working 100%? And you don't get mixed orientations and avoid the error "Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and `shouldAutorotate` returns `YES`".

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If your iPad app is landscape only in all conditions, just do these 3 steps :

**1) In your app delegate**

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

**2) Create a category header**

```
#import "UIViewController+OrientationFix.h"

@implementation UIViewController (OrientationFix)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

@end
```

**3) Create a category implementation**

```
#import "UIImagePickerController+OrientationFix.h"

@implementation UIImagePickerController (OrientationFix)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

@end
```

Note: You don't need to import these categories anywhere, just enough they are compiled with the project

Note: no need to implement these methods in any VC

Note: no need to change your plist supported orientations

**This is tested and working under any conditions**

Comment: What about if the App isn't landscape only?

Comment: than it should be no problem, as the app support any orientation anyway

Comment: You're not supposed to override a class's methods in a category. Which method actually gets used is technically undefined, even if it always seems to work. Apple could change something that would break it at a future point in time.

Comment: "Which method actually gets used is technically undefined" thats not true

Comment: I have implemented all the things as discussed above but the thing is that my camera is rotated 90 degree and comes in half the screen when i switch to landscape orientation !!

Comment: than you did smth. wrong. or smth. else is changing the bahaviour (note this is tested for iOS7)

Comment: @ParvezBelim is right. Camera showing 90 Degree rotated.

Comment: than you did smth. wrong. or smth. else is changing the bahaviour (note this is tested for iOS7) –

Comment: That worked for me like a charm. Thank u so much buddy. I was searching from couple of days.You saved my lots of time. Thanks again.

Comment: **IT WORKS IF YOU FOLLOW STEPS PROPERLY.**

Comment: Will this pass appstore?

Comment: I followed the steps exactly and I can't get it to work in IOS7, has anyone gotten it working there?

Comment: @ScottRowley
1) copy/paste method to app delegate
2) file -> new -> file -> objective-c category -> (Category) OrientationFix (Category on) UIViewController
3) file -> new -> file -> objective-c category -> (Category) OrientationFix (Category on) UIImagePickerController

Comment: That's exactly what I did :(

Comment: @ScottRowley works for me on iOS7, for camera + photo album both.

Comment: This works on iOS7, we must implement in both UIViewController and UIImagePickerController

Comment: @Collin, this works great. Just a question. I replaced first with an plist setting (or setting in Target - General - Device Orientation), but that does not works, why?

Comment: The Perfect solution Peter...Thank you very much..!@!!

Comment: This works on both iPhone and iPad, with iOS7 and iOS8. I have implemented it into my project. Perfect.

Comment: This does not work on iOS 8.1.2. Have created a test project following the steps above here for anyone to try: https://github.com/ricsantos/image-picker-test

Comment: It Shows me This error.

Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x7fcaec013400>  on <MFSideMenuContainerViewController: 0x7fcaea4e8f20> which is already presenting <UIAlertController: 0x7fcaec90a220>

Please help me

Comment: probably you have some other modal presented?

Comment: Didn't need step 3 in iOS 8.4

Comment: Worked fine in iOS 8.4. Didn't need step 3.

Comment: Hi @PeterLapisu Code is working for me but Portrait mode is getting enabled by this. I have game and i dont want to enable portrait mode in any situation. Any idea?

Comment: @smitpatel this shouldn't happen, looks like you have maybe some other problem there?

Comment: this is the only route that worked for me with Xamarin.iOS

Answer (score 41):

I have seen this code from Apple's Sample Code.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

Due to this **UIModalPresentationCurrentContext** `UIImagePickerController` will be opened as per device's current orientation.

Comment: This is the best answer. Using categories is a hack. This works with photo, video and library source type. Tested with iOS8.3.

Comment: This answer is more beautiful than any that I've seen.

Comment: iOS 8.4: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES'

Comment: Work like charm on iOS 8.4.

Comment: Works on iOS 8.4.1. We should vote more her and ask this to be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: IOS 9 Works! This is the correct answer. Also for Swift code: imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext

Comment: Elsurudo, please note that you still need to tick Device Orientation Portrait to prevent the crash.

Comment: This didn't work for me. But imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen; did.

Comment: This didn't work for me either on iOS 9.2 — it doesn't avoid the crash if unless you tick Portrait in your app's orientation settings.

Comment: It can present vc on iPad pro.But the displayed exception.

Comment: imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext  ... worked perfect for me in iOS10.3 & Swift3.0

Answer (score 1):

Apple's documentation says:

"Important: The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only."

Although, it works fine in landscape for full screen and on iOS 6.

[UIImagePickerController class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Peter Lapisu suggestion above. It doesn't work for me (maybe i'm on iOS 8.3) but i was able to modified it to fixed my orientation issues. My codes are below

In app delegate

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

UIImagePickerController category

```
@implement UIImagePickerController (extensions)
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
}

@end
```

UIViewController category

```
@implementation UIViewController (extensions)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Although most answers recommend using `.currentContext`, I have found out after dismissing the imagepicker, everything was wrong.

On an Landscaped iPad, *imho* it's best if you would use `.formSheet`:

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
picker.delegate = self
self.present(picker, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Swift 4` solution

Make sure that when you are having the ViewController embedded in a NavigationViewController to have the fix there. It won't work adding this restriction to the ViewController then...

```
import UIKit

class MainNavigationViewController: UINavigationController {

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .landscape
    }
}
```

And of course the code mentioned above for the AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .all
}
```

Btw this is only necessary for iOS 10 and below. Apple seems to have fixed it from iOS 11 and above...